# Error creating a computed column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have this question regarding computed columns. This is the first time that I work with them, and I do not understand why I'm getting an error.

Let's assume I have a table already created:

```
create table testComputed
(
    a int null,
    b int null
)
```

Now, I want to update it with another couple of columns including a computed one:

```
alter table testcomputed add c int null;
alter table testcomputed add d int null;
alter table testcomputed add e as c + d;
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
> Invalid column name 'c'
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
> Invalid column name 'd'

What is missing in the code, why the computed column is not created?

Comment: Microsoft's syntax shows `alter table testcomputed add e as (c + d);`, with parenthesis around the computation. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Put the last `ALTER` statement in a separate batch; the parsing is failing here as the columns don't exist at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in the comment, the problem here is that the parsing/compilation is failing. Prior to the batch actually running it is parsed, and only *some* objects/properties benefit from the parser knowing that the object was created previous in the batch, and thus not failing; columns are not one of these. As such when the batch is parsed, the columns `c` and `d` *do not* exist at that point, and so the the parser generates an error.

The simple solution would be to separate the latter statement into a separate batch. In an application like SSMS that would just mean adding a batch separator (traditionally `GO`):

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.testcomputed ADD c int NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.testcomputed ADD d int NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.testcomputed ADD e AS c + d;
GO
```

If you need to do it in the same batch, you could defer the parsing by using `sys.sp_executsql`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.testcomputed ADD c int NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.testcomputed ADD d int NULL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE dbo.testcomputed ADD e AS c + d;';
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.testcomputed ADD c int NULL, d int NULL, e AS c + d;` works fine as a single statement